# iPhone UITableView refesh data in Delegate

Tags: iphone, uitableview, refresh

How do I have a UITableView be notified that the data it is using is new and all old data/cells should be flushed.

I have a search bar that will cause the UITableView to be refreshed when new queries are entered.

Comment: Not sure what the question is.  Have you tried calling reloadData on the table view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example would be:

```
[myTableView reloadData];
```